# Can Pipes be used in Javascript or Typescript?

Tags: angular, angular2-template

*This is a hopelessly naive question but I've been wrestling with it for a couple of hours now.*

Can Pipes be called from JavaScript/TypeScript or are they only meant to be used in `templates`? All the references and [tutorials](http://voidcanvas.com/angular-2-pipes-filters/) I've looked at show Pipes being used in the templates only.

I'm don't have a hard use case for this but I'm playing around with the various elements of Angular2 and could imagine that I might have a need to use a Pipe directly and not recode it in JS/TS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, a pipe is just code, so you could use it as code without using it in your template. For example, I have a ProductFilterPipe that filters a list of products. We could use that pipe in code as follows:

```
filterProducts() : void {
    let productFilterPipe = new ProductFilterPipe();
    let filteredList = productFilterPipe.transform(this.products, "am");
    console.log(filteredList);
}
```

So it is possible.

Comment: That's correct. Also if you want to use it with Typescript you can have in the **providers: [...]** and then pass it to the constructor, so the instance is handled by Angular2 Dependecy Injection. Not sure about the built in pipes though, I don't know if those are exported or from where to import them.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the default Angular pipes (e.g. DecimalPipe, CurrencyPipe) by importing:

```
import {DecimalPipe} from '@angular/common';
```

and then using it by

```
DecimalPipe.prototype.transform(value, formattingString)
```